# HTML5 flexible box model height calculation

Tags: html

after researching the flexible box model for a whole day, I must say I really like it. It implements the functionality I implement in JavaScript in a fast and clean way. One thing however bugs me:

***I can't expand a div to take the full size calculated by the flexible box model!!!***

To illustrate it I'll proved an example. In it the two flexible places take the exact with and height, but the div inside it only takes the height of the `"<p>...</p>"` element. For this example it doesn't matter but what I originally was trying was placing a "flexible box model" inside another "flexible box model" and this must be possible in my opinion

```css
html, body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#box-1 {
  background-color: #E8B15B;

}
#box-2 {
  background-color: #C1D652;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


.flexbox {
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display: box;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
H1 {
  width: auto;
}
#box-1 {
  height: auto;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;

  -moz-box-flex: 3;
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
  box-flex: 3;
}
#box-2 {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 50px;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;

  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}
#fullsize{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="flexbox">
  <div id="box-1" class="flexbox">
    <div id="fullsize">
      <p>Hallo welt</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="box-2" class="flexbox"> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must also make the div you want to expand a flex-box as well and add a flex value.
This fixes the problem.

```
#fullsize{
    background-color: red;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    display: -moz-box;

    box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
}
```