# Set a div's height to a percentage of sibling div

Tags: css

I have three sibling divs in a row:

Right div: A div that has height determined by its text content.

Center div: A div that should match the height of the Right div.

**Left div: A div that I *want* to set at 50% height of the Right div.**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsnyder/h7gc12wb/4/)

CSS attempt using flexbox with Left div not working:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
.center {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: palegreen;
}
```

The only way I have discovered to allow the Left div to calculate a percentage of the Right div's height is to use `position: absolute`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676022/html5-flexible-box-model-height-calculation/15388247#15388247).

Absolute positioning is less than ideal, because it prevents me from using normal layout flow to set the three divs next to each other in a row.

**Is there any way I can set the Left div to a percentage of the Right div's height, without needing to use a fixed horizontal layout to set the three divs in a row?**

The layout only needs to work in recent Chrome, so browser incompatibilities are not an issue.  I am open to solutions using flexbox or table layout.

Comment: Unless you put them within a containing element and set the height on that, then there is no way to do this using only CSS.

Comment: I know you have posted a link to an answer, that includes this as a workaround:  http://jsfiddle.net/h7gc12wb/5/ but you wrote also `"Absolute positioning is less than ideal, because it prevents me from using normal layout flow to set the three divs next to each other"`. When you use `position: absolute;` on a child of `.left` you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what restrictions you have on your HTML structure. But a simple way to do what you want is to set the `left` div as an equal height `table-cell` div, and inside it, an inner div with `50%` height. It will not affect the elements flow:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gc12wb/7/)

```css
.container {
    display: table;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
}

.left > div {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.center {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum porttitor vitae ante quis suscipit.
    </div>
</div>
```