# Flexbox height issue with nested flex-grow boxes in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, sticky-footer

Here's a flexbox challenge that I can't seem to find a solution for.

Using BS4 alpha 6 flexbox utils, I'm trying to make a **full-height layout** with a main content area, and sidebar that **scroll independently**. On the main left side there is to be a stick-to-bottom footer (that pushes down when the content is higher than 100%). Additionally, the main content area itself has a stick-to-bottom footer. I'm using `flex-grow:1` for the sticky footers.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper row">
        <div class="col-9 inner d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
            <div class="main bg-info p-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                <div class="p-3">
                    <h3>Main content area</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-faded p-3">inner footer</div>
            </div>
            <footer class="bg-inverse text-white p-3">footer</footer>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-faded p-3 sidebar">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So far so good...**
[image]

**Problem when content is taller...**

[image]

To resolve this problem, I can remove `display:flex` from the inner container, but then the inner footer is longer pushed to the bottom:

**No sticky footer w/o display:flex on inner**

[image]

https://codeply.com/go/2vnNsK0PZ6

I can also set max-height and `overflow-y:auto` on the inner content area which works but causes a scroll only on the inner area. I want the entire left side to scroll instead.

[image]

So, **the question is**, how can a make a full height layout with separate scrolling sides and multiple sticky footers that "push" down as needed.

One more caveat is that the inner footer must remain inside the `.main` div.

https://codeply.com/go/2vnNsK0PZ6

**Edit:**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123701/nested-flex-container-not-stretching-to-the-remaining-space) is similar except the scrolling is only in the innermost div. When that innermost div gets squished I want it to push everything down, and then the outer div to scroll.

Solved with `flex:1 0 auto` instead of `flex-grow:1`

https://codeply.com/go/CrsFF0xJQu

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: auto` to `.p-3`?

Comment: Just the parent of the main content area.

Comment: Then back to your original code, on `.main`, switch from `flex: 1 0 0` to `flex: 1 0 auto`.

Comment: I think that just might work! https://www.codeply.com/go/CrsFF0xJQu